# How to access local external drives from a Remote Ubuntu Machine?

Tags: macos, ubuntu, micro-sd-card

Is it possible for local (Mac) external drives to be accessed via a remote PC (Ubuntu)? I want to be able to build and flash my custom Android ROM which is hosted on my Ubuntu machine and write those images to an SD card that is connected to my local Macbook. Essentially, I want to plug in my SD card into the Macbook and reference that drive on the Ubuntu machine through SSH.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't have a Mac, so not certain and therefor a comment. Assuming that the Mac has sshd and uses block devices and similar. command line tools to Linux (which I think is the case) you could use SSH and cat to write the block device directly - eg something like cat /path/to/image file | ssh Mac.IP.addr "cat > /dev/blockdevonmac"

Comment: I should've clarified further in my original post. The script that I want to run on the Ubuntu machine needs a reference to the block device on my Macbook in order to partition and format the SD card. e.g. 'sudo ./var-mksdcard.sh -f imageName /dev/blockdevonmac;sync'